# C++ Dependency management best practice

Tags: c++, gradle, dependencies, nuget

I am writing a multiplatform (windows and Linux) application in c++ using boost asio. I have previous experience using gradle for automated Java dependency management and found the tools for c++ are not as good. Currently the best I've found is nuget for visual studio.

My question is, when there are no good tools for automated dependency management, what is the best practice for publishing a project on github? Should I supply pages of documentation on how to set up the build environment and where to download third party dependencies, or, should I supply everything required to compile the project?

Also please if possible provide good reasons for your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my observation, supplying documents on how to set up the build environment is a general way.

It can make your project more portable. That is, users can select the dependencies they like to build. And you don't have to update your project due to the update of dependencies.

A very important thing you need to keep in mind is that you should consider how to make building issue easy. Make sure that your project is general enough to fit the dependencies. And the document should be clear and compact.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to remove the need for the user to have to locate specific versions of files. So far I've used cmake's find and git submodules. https://foonathan.github.io/blog/2016/07/07/cmake-dependency-handling.html